# Yet another ffmpeg concat audio sync issue

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I've read through dozens of posts, tried many suggestions, nothing seems to work for me. The funny part is that the video is fine in some players (e.g. Quicktime) but not the others (e.g. Chrome).

This is what I currently use:

```
ffmpeg -i segment.mp4 -q 0 -c copy segment.ts
ffmpeg -f concat -i videos.txt -c copy -y final.mp4
```

This is what ffmpeg shows for the originals

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '52M35S_1710280355.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2024-03-12T21:53:35.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:59.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 851 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Audio: opus (Opus / 0x7375704F), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 10 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-03-12T21:53:35.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080, 836 kb/s, 10.02 fps, 10 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-03-12T21:53:35.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Comment: What is the issue here? All you wrote is "it doesn't work" and "it differs per player". Be more specific please.

Comment: @Destroy666 The problem is that the input is somehow using **HEVC** video codec together with an **Opus** audio codec. Doing a `codec copy` command means, later on, Chrome will reject the output MP4 file that has Opus audio since it's not a valid MPEG codec.

Comment: @Demiurg Chrome expects an MP4 with AAC audio (last time I tried even MP3 was still being rejected when inside MP4). As for a solution... Try: `ffmpeg -i segment.mp4 c:v copy c:a aac segment.ts` but I think making TS should be a later step after first extracting & convert the audio part (_eg:_ you mux two input files into one `-i vid.mp4 -i audio.m4a -c copy segment.ts`).

Comment: Please re-read the question you posted and note that there is not actually a question anywhere in it. Then use the EDIT button and add a clear and specific question. The things you've added down here in comments should be added to the question.